# Maven 2 checkstyle plugin version 2.5 - Problem with configLocation

Tags: maven-2, checkstyle

I am using checkstyle plugin in maven 2. I now want to switch my config file, from the default one to a) an online file, or b) a local file. I tried the following two things, which both didnt work. Any suggestions?

A) Local file, which is directly in my project folder next to the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

B) Remote file, that is stored on a server

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>http://stud.hs-heilbronn.de/~nischmid/development/checkstyle-config.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Both cases result in an error like this:

> [INFO] An error has occurred in
>   Checkstyle report generation. Embedded
>   error: Failed during checkstyle
>   execution Could not find resource
>   'file:checkstyle.xml'.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen several issues related to `configLocation` in [Jira](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCHECKSTYLE) with the version 2.5 of the plugin (like [MCHECKSTYLE-129](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-129) or [MCHECKSTYLE-131](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-131)), both a) and b) just work fine with the version 2.4.

So, unless you're using Maven 3, I suggest to rollback to 2.4 for now:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
  </configuration>
</plugins>
```

or

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <configLocation>http://stud.hs-heilbronn.de/~nischmid/development/checkstyle-config.xml</configLocation>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As a side note, for a multi-modules build, have a look at the [Multimodule Configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html).

Comment: Swithing back to version 2.4 did solve problem a), however problem b) resists. I followed the instructions given in MCHECKSTYLE-129 which solved problem b). So I have checkstyle plugin version 2.5 with plexus-resources 1.0-alpha-7-SNAPSHOT and everything works fine. Thanks Pascal!

Comment: @Nils Weird, I tested b) with your URL and it worked for me with 2.4. Anyway, if you solved it with 2.5 by adding the plexus-resources dependency, that's fine :)

Answer (score 6):

I've been trying to use version 3.0.1 of the Checkstyle plugin and found `configLocation` has no effect. Tried the approach above, but still no luck.

To summarise, the answer above probably does work, but you might need to set a property `checkstyle.config.location`.

Using `-X` to get debug output, I saw:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) configLocation = config/sun_checks.xml
```

Scrolling further back in the log, it looks like `configLocation` isn't being set:

```
<configLocation default-value="config/sun_checks.xml">${checkstyle.config.location}</configLocation>
```

Based on that message, I set the property in the global `<properties>` as follows:

```
<checkstyle.config.location>${basedir}/config/checkstyle-configuration.xml</checkstyle.config.location>
```

This worked, but caused the plugin to throw an exception. After some Googling, I added the following to the checkstyle configuration file:

```
<module name="Checker">
  ...
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    ...
    <property name="cacheFile" value=""/>
```

For completeness, the last step came from the following Jira, marked as resolved in 2.8. The difference is it seems to work with an empty value, avoiding the need to set up a `${cachefile}` property:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-159

Comment: Had to put "file://" in front though. <checkstyle.config.location>file://${basedir}/config/checkstyle-configuration.xml</checkstyle.config.location>

Answer (score 2):

Maybe helpful for someone else who needs to still find a workaround. 
By the way i had the same problem and the file is suppose to be searched in /classes/.xml or folders from here. But since it is looking directly after the project folder i included

```
<configuration>
<configLocation>src\main\resources\checkstyle-checker-dev.xml</configLocation>
</configuration>
```

Note: configLocation has L caps

Also you can define a global variable in environment and use here
Note: This is only a workaround, it needs to work as stated in the above lines.